# How can I access programming class globally in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

**I want to declare a class like below**

```
class Customer{
 constructor(){
    this.id;       
    this.name;
    this.email;
    this.username;       
    this.password;
   }
}
```

**I want to create its instance in any component in vuejs like this**

```
export default {
  name: 'TestCompotent',
  data()
  {
    return{
      MainCutomer: new Customer()      
    }
  },
}
```

**Please advice me, how can I do that?**

Comment: without importing in every component?

Comment: Just import the class something like this above export default - `import MainCustomer from `./path/Customer.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/embed/frosty-elion-b1vyh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**.

**/src/class/Customer.js:**

```
class Customer {
  constructor(id, name, email, username, password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }
}

export default Customer;
```

**/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h3>TEST PAGE</h3>
    <h5>Main Customer</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>ID: {{ MainCustomer.id }}</li>
      <li>Name: {{ MainCustomer.name }}</li>
      <li>Username: {{ MainCustomer.username }}</li>
      <li>E-mail: {{ MainCustomer.email }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Customer from "./../class/Customer";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    let MainCustomer = new Customer(
      1,
      "Tony",
      "tony.stark@avengers.com",
      "Tony007",
      "myPassword123"
    );
    return {
      MainCustomer: MainCustomer,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```